# "There was a category move error" when trying to move a subcategory up 1 level to main category

Tags: category, error, error-message

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty
```

We are trying to move a subcategory up one level to make it one of the main categories and we get the following *non-descriptive Error*:

**There was a category move error.**

I googled the Error but there just seem to be too many possible causes. I am including my Error log reports here hoping it would narrow down the root cause:

**exception.log:**

```
[2021-12-03 10:45:54] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2021-12-03 10:51:52] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
[2021-12-03 11:07:54] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

**debug.log:**

```
[2021-12-03 11:03:52] main.DEBUG: URI '/index.php/wishlist/index/add/product/2324/form_key/VTQu8ILDH7fRU343/'' cannot be accessed with GET method (Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add) [] []
[2021-12-03 11:03:52] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/HttpMethodValidator.php:69)"} []
[2021-12-03 11:07:03] main.INFO: 0 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:03] main.INFO: 299 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:04] main.INFO: 8 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.013170003890991,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":378896,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":204518304} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.17401599884033,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":3211648,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":204901480} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: 4 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: 17 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: 4 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.13507103919983,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":3707520,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":204867760} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job ddg_automation_sms_order_messages is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job ddg_automation_sms_order_messages is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.033495903015137,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":4828984,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":204508720} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job security_deactivate_expired_users is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.032136917114258,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":198048,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":204997040} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job security_deactivate_expired_users is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0052359104156494,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":194888,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":206801104} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_index_refresh_price is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_index_refresh_price is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.020325899124146,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":3558432,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":207084000} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.062212944030762,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":6123128,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":210782136} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00092411041259766,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1512,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":216932296} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_attribute_value_synchronize is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.001378059387207,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":21328,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":216972040} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_clean_orders is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_clean_orders is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0054678916931152,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":86712,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":219721224} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00019693374633789,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":219969232} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00018405914306641,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":219975208} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00019502639770508,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":219980336} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0001828670501709,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":219985912} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00018095970153809,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":220012520} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00016999244689941,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":220330864} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00017285346984863,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":220620472} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00018501281738281,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":220946072} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00052285194396973,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1504,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":220967544} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job expired_tokens_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job expired_tokens_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011289119720459,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":3064,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":221012024} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job captcha_delete_old_attempts is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job captcha_delete_old_attempts is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00093388557434082,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":23760,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":221020064} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Cron Job captcha_delete_expired_images is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job captcha_delete_expired_images is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.009727954864502,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":621352,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":221075992} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00018000602722168,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":222822400,"emalloc_start":221735728} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job messagequeue_clean_outdated_locks is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job messagequeue_clean_outdated_locks is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00066184997558594,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1488,"realmem_start":224919552,"emalloc_start":221754120} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00023198127746582,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1008,"realmem_start":224919552,"emalloc_start":222879992} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job newsletter_send_all is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0047879219055176,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":384104,"realmem_start":224919552,"emalloc_start":222888064} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071907043457031,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2360,"realmem_start":224919552,"emalloc_start":223279200} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_acart_refresh is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_acart_refresh is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.016503095626831,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":615992,"realmem_start":227016704,"emalloc_start":223960648} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_advanced_review_reminder is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_advanced_review_reminder is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0016779899597168,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":69520,"realmem_start":227016704,"emalloc_start":224821592} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amblog_scheduled_post is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amblog_scheduled_post is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0060958862304688,"count":1,"realmem":2097152,"emalloc":610024,"realmem_start":227016704,"emalloc_start":225645696} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_cron_activity is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_cron_activity is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00017714500427246,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":229113856,"emalloc_start":226260296} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_amdelivery_reminder is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_amdelivery_reminder is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.2696681022644,"count":1,"realmem":10485760,"emalloc":9360968,"realmem_start":229113856,"emalloc_start":226644744} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_mostviewed_analytics_collect_view is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_mostviewed_analytics_collect_view is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0037369728088379,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":53696,"realmem_start":239599616,"emalloc_start":236423224} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_mostviewed_analytics_collect_click is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amasty_mostviewed_analytics_collect_click is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0012369155883789,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1072,"realmem_start":239599616,"emalloc_start":236476512} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_capture_updates is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_capture_updates is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.002953052520752,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":67040,"realmem_start":239599616,"emalloc_start":236705320} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_authorization_updates is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job get_amazon_authorization_updates is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.002795934677124,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":138528,"realmem_start":239599616,"emalloc_start":236873096} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds is run [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:06] main.INFO: Cron Job amazon_payments_process_queued_refunds is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0029909610748291,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":131872,"realmem_start":239599616,"emalloc_start":237023208} [] []
[2021-12-03 11:07:54] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: category_id in /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/Category/Plugin/Storage.php on line 57 at /home/MYWEBSITE/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

**system.log:**

```
[2021-12-03 11:07:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
```

**What can I do to resolve this?**

---

**Updated on December 7th, 2021 with a workaround:**

I was able to make this work via this workaround:

1. Go to `Catalog -> Categories` and note the sub-category's ID and the main category's ID that you want to move the sub-category under.
2. Open up phpMyAdmin and go to the `catalog_category_entity` table.
3. In this table, find the subcategory by finding the subcategory ID in the `entity_ID` field. Click 'Edit' on that row and change the `parent_id` to the Main category ID (where you want to move the sub-category to) and then click Go.

This does then allow me to move the category in `Catalog -> Categories`. Reindex afterwards.

**As this appears to be a workaround only and as it happens with ALL of my subcategories when I try to move them, what would be a permanent solution to this problem?** *Would it make sense for me to go through all the categories and assign the correct parent ID in phpMyAdmin?*

Comment: May be indexing issue, make sure are doing correctly `indexing`, and `deployed correctly`,` try using luma theme` also `disble amasty module` and than `move category watchout again logs`

Comment: @Zahid H Thank you for your comment. When you say to make sure I am doing indexing correctly - do you mean running the command via SSH? That's how I reindex. What does 'deployed correctly' mean and how can I check that? We have to use the Smartwave Porto theme.

Comment: I mean to say; try `compile, upgrade, static contents deploy,index,cache flush` commands via `SHH` and use default theme and disable Amasty module and final words, if you are using chrome then use different browser. hope this will resolve your issue